# When i update gradle SDK's, popup the error is Recieved status code 403 from server-Forbidden

Tags: android, facebook, android-gradle-plugin, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-audience-network

I am using Facebook audience network latest SDK `implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.32.0'` and gradle version is `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1`, but I get an error

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.32.0.
>
> Could not resolve com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.32.0.
>   Required by:
>   project :app
>   Could not resolve com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.32.0.
>   Could not get resource 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/facebook/android/audience-network-sdk/4.32.0/audience-network-sdk-4.32.0.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/facebook/android/audience-network-sdk/4.32.0/audience-network-sdk-4.32.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

How to solve this? Please give me a solution .. thanks in advance

Comment: please anyone give me a solution. Past 3 days i search many answer but, still the issue is not done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version 4.32.0 does not exist at the moment.

Try with `4.+` in order to let gradle pick up the latest version.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.28.1'
}
```

Then you will be able to use this library.

PS: `audiance-network-sdk` is also using some google libraries which require the repository `jcenter()`

Comment: Hi, thanks for replaying, the issue from facebook side, now they are changed their doc [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/download].